# how can I re-use the window created by `display-buffer-in-side-window`?

Tags: buffers, window

I'm creating a window at the bottom of the frame with `display-buffer-in-side-window` and it displays a given buffer, I would like to have another buffer created but re-use that exact same window.

How do I do that? I'm keeping track of the value yield by `(get-buffer-window (current-buffer))`.

```
(defvar tortuga-first-open-window nil
  "Track the window of the first shell opened.")


(defun tortuga-shell ()
  "Open the first terminal at the bottom of the frame."
  (interactive)
  (if tortuga-first-open-window
      (set-window-buffer tortuga-first-open-window (tortuga-shell--create-new))
    (select-window
     (display-buffer-in-side-window
      (save-window-excursion
        (tortuga-shell--create-new))
      `((side . bottom)
        (window-height . ,tortuga-first-open-window-height)))))
  (setq tortuga-first-open-window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer))))

(defun tortuga-shell--create-new ()
  "Create a new eshell."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((count (+ 1 (length tortuga-shell-buffer-list)))
         (new-eshell-buffer (get-buffer-create (format "%s<%d>" eshell-buffer-name count))))
    (tortuga-shell-setup new-eshell-buffer)
    (add-to-list 'tortuga-shell-buffer-list new-eshell-buffer)
    new-eshell-buffer))

(defun tortuga-shell-setup (buffer)
  "Setup new buffer BUFFER as eshell buffer."
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (eshell-mode)
    (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'tortuga-after-kill-buffer nil :local)
    (local-set-key (kbd tortuga-hydra-start-key) 'tortuga-hydra/body)))
```

Comment: How about using `set-window-buffer`?  If you create a new buffer, do so in a way that does not display it; and, then use `set-window-buffer`.

Comment: @lawlist I modified my code to use `set-window-buffer` but is not working, the buffer remains and the new one is created and not displayed in the side window.

Comment: Due to the complexity of the display-buffer family of functions, a minimal working example that we can all work with would be very helpful.

Comment: @lawlist I have updated my question with the actual code I'm trying.